# How to express a sequence of matrix multiplications $\prod_{i=1}^{n}M_i$ but starting from $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, notation

Having square matrices $M_j\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, with $j\in\{1\,..\,n\}$, what notation should be used to express the following sequence of multiplications?:
\begin{align}
M_n\to M_{n-1}M_n\to M_{n-2}M_{n-1}M_n \to \ldots \to M_1\ldots M_{n-2}M_{n-1}M_n
\end{align}

I've thought of using the productory: $\prod^{1}_{j=n}M_j$, with an additional disclaimer indicating that the operations are left-multiplications. However I feel there may be a better way since I believe the standard use of $\prod$ is for right-multiplications.

The closest questions that I've found are this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871304/is-there-a-way-to-express-factorial-like-matrix-multiplication) and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714491/is-there-such-a-thing-as-backwards-sigma). However, left-multiplications are not contemplated.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would avoid any fancy notation as different readers may have different ideas of what order the product is taken.  I'd just say:  consider, for each $k$, the matrix $P_k=M_1M_2\ldots M_k$.

Comment: @Ruy I see your point. In fact I may have been complicating myself. $$P_k = \prod_{i=k}^n M_i$$ works best as suggested by ecrin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the sequence $N_k=M_kM_{k+1}\dots M_{n-1}M_n$, it suffices to write $$N_k=\prod_{i=k}^{n}M_i.$$

If you want to write the $n$-th term, $i.e.$ $M_1M_{2}\dots M_{n-1}M_n$, remark that the product is associative, that is it doesn't change if you consider $AB$ as $B$ right multiplied by $A$ or $A$ left-multiplied by $B$, so I'd suggest the usual notation $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}.$$

Finally, if you want to write $M_nM_{n-1}\dots M_{2}M_1$, as in the first linked solution, the best option could be $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}M_{n-i+1}.$$

Comment: Yes :) The 1st definition is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Probably this one $$\prod_{j=n-k} ^ {n} M_{j}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)